# How to control a bottom sheet width?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I need to a bottom sheet didn't take all width on the tablet. But it ignore `layout_width` attribute in xml. How can I make it?
My bottom sheet class:

```
public class DetailsFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Create fragment root view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);
        //Set toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        Drawable icClose = VectorDrawable.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(icClose);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.details);
        RecyclerView rvContent = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvContent);
        FullExpandedListManager lm = new FullExpandedListManager(getContext());
        rvContent.setLayoutManager(lm);
        rvContent.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvContent.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if it's the best solution but it works for me at least.

```
public class DetailsFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new BottomSheetDialog(getContext(), getTheme());
    }

    public static class BottomSheetDialog extends android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog {

        public BottomSheetDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        protected BottomSheetDialog(@NonNull Context context, final boolean cancelable,
                                    OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
            super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
        }

        public BottomSheetDialog(@NonNull Context context, @StyleRes final int theme) {
            super(context, theme);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().setLayout(300 /*our width*/, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I tried to set a dialog width in the `onStart()` method but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Cool. Worked as a champ

Comment: Just this adding this line in `onCreate` `getWindow().setLayout(300 /*our width*/, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` seems to work for a `BottomSheetDialog`

Comment: Perfect answer on changing dialog width perfectly.

Comment: NOTE: When doing it this way I faced some weird issues with bottom sheet. On certain physical devices (e.g. Pixel 4a and Pixel 6 Pro on Android 12 but not 13) it seemed to calculate the inside width wrongly and some UI elements overlapped the right edge of the screen. These issues only occurred on physical devices and not virtual devices. Also some button touch events were not registered if they are inside a `ListView`. After reverting this change, all the issues disappeared. So use at your own risk.

Answer (score 3):

`BottomSheetBehaviour.maxWidth` did the job for me