# How to set width of a Modal Bottom Sheet in xml?

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, material-design

I am trying to make the width of the bottom sheet to only wrap content and show on the bottom right of the screen. I am using an android tablet as the device. I have searched through the Bottom Sheet Material Design website for implementation and any properties in xml that could control width. I tried to set width to wrap content but no luck.

This is the size I am looking for:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a bottom sheet"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_sheet_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_sheet_btn1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: By "Modal Bottom Sheet", do you mean that you're using a `BottomSheetDialog[Fragment]`?

Comment: By Modal, I'm meaning a Modal type bottom sheet instead of a standard one. https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom/#modal-bottom-sheet

Comment: Right, but "modal" has a specific meaning that is rather independent of implementation. I'm asking what you're using to effect this.

Comment: Forget about the modal part. I'm just asking what you're using for the bottom sheet. Are you using a `BottomSheetDialog[Fragment]`? Or is this a `View` inside a `CoordinatorLayout` with `BottomSheetBehavior`? Something else?

Comment: I actually forgot to put this inside a `CoordinatorLayout` with `BottomSheetBehavior`. I originally had it set up with `BottomSheetFragment :BottomSheetDialogFragment()` and then calling this view to show from a `button.onClickListener()`. Placing it inside `CoordinatorLayout` should do the trick. Thanks for bringing that up!

Comment: Sure thing. If you do that, though, you'll have to handle the modal behavior yourself, 'cause it'll be just another `View` inside the `CoordinatorLayout`. With the `Dialog`, it was inherently modal. Just FYI. Cheers!

Comment: Yes thank you for the information! I had created a bottom sheet fragment a few months ago this same way. I just forgot about having to place it within the `Coordinator Layout`.

Answer (score 1):

What I did: extend `BottomSheetDialogFragment` like this:

```kotlin
class MyBottomSheet(
    private val mContext: Context
): BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    // ...

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return object: BottomSheetDialog(mContext, theme) {
            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Solution was based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/38291199/191761

NOTE: When doing it this way I faced some weird issues with bottom sheet. On certain physical devices (e.g. Pixel 4a and Pixel 6 Pro on Android 12 but not 13) it seemed to calculate the width wrongly and some UI elements overlapped the right edge of the screen. These issues only occurred on physical devices and not virtual devices. Also some button touch events were not registered if they are inside a `ListView`. So use at your own risk.

---

EDIT: Another way to achieve a similar thing is to use `BottomSheetBehavior.maxWidth`, adding something like this to your subclass's `onCreateView`:

`bsd.behavior.maxWidth = context?.resources?.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.bottomsheet_max_width) ?: 320`

This requires you to create a matching dimension in `dimens.xml` obviously.

It won't wrap the content as well as the above solution, but it doesn't suffer from the same bugs.

Comment: Great solution! Just also want to add that we can get the full width by displayMetrics
`behavior.maxWidth = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [library](https://github.com/HeyAlex/CornerSheet) where i already handle all cases for making such material component